# Can enemies see you in the brush if they have vision of your team mate?

Tags: league-of-legends

If a team mate walks into the brush I am standing in, just after walking onto a Nidalee trap for example, can the enemy then see me too?

Edit: To clarify, I mean when a team mate is globally visible (nidalee trap) and walks into a bush where you are standing.

Comment: You mean if one of _your_ teammates enters the bush you are in? Or if someone from _their_ team enters the bush?

Comment: If it's like DotA or StarCraft:BW, attacking from fog of war reveals vision in a small radius around the attacking unit to the attacked player.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your teammate hits a Nidalee trap and walks into a bush you're in, it doesn't reveal the entire bush, only the x-distance visible radius around him/her. If he/she comes into the x-distance with you in the bush you will be visible as well.

For a distance example, see:

[image: this]

Comment: What is the range of this x-distance you speak of?

Comment: @theorise Can't find a specific range number, but post has been edited with an image of someone with the debuff for reference.

Comment: Really weird scenario, I didn't even know this x-distance existed. Good answer though thanks.

Comment: @theorise Just for clarity when I say x-distance I mean whatever the visibility range on the bushwhack debuff is. It's just a substitute since I can't find a real number for you.

Answer (score 3):

If any person, ward, trap, mushroom, etc on their team can see you, their entire team can see you.

The exception to this is if you're in a bush invisible.  Then, someone or something that can detect invisibility must be inside the same bush to see you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if a teammate walking in while already globally visible (from a Nidalee trap etc) will reveal you.

However, *attacking* from the brush while standing right next to a teammate will definitely reveal both of you to the enemy team.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you become visible to everyone on the team.